# What is the "ID of the navigator" provided to React Navigation's NativeStackScreenProps?

Tags: typescript, react-navigation, navigation-drawer

The React Navigation documents provide some suggestions on TypeScript type checking that [include the following](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript#type-checking-screens) for type checking screens:

```js
type Props = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'Profile', 'MyStack'>;
```

The final argument is the (optional) "ID of the navigator", but it's not clear where that comes from or what it represents.

What is the "ID of the navigator" provided to `NativeStackScreenProps`?

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#id

Comment: @satya164 Yes, but that doesn't say much. It begs the question why screens that are already together in for [a root navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/#type-checking-screens) can be potentially given different IDs. What form should it take? Where does it's value come from?

Comment: you can give different ID in the type but that doesn't mean it'll be correct. the type is like that for backward compatibility, any other way would need too many changes